# how to save RSS to xml file java

Tags: java, xml, rss

I want to save an RSS feed to an xml document on my computer. I'm using XPath with Java to parse the XML myself, so all I want is a file that contains the source (XML) I see when I view the source of the website's RSS page.

In other words, instead of copying and pasting the source of the RSS page into a file I save as an XML file, I'd like to write a program that pulls this for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need to introduce a library to do that!

Simply get an [`URL`-object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) on the Rss-Feed you want to "download" and use the [`openConnection()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) to get an [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

You can then use it's [`getInputStream()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream%28%29). From this InputStream you can read the unparsed source of the RSS document (you should wrapp it with a [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)).

This can then be saved as a String (in memory) or directly written to the HDD by using a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

---

An example-implementation can be found here: https://gist.github.com/2320294

Comment: Thanks!  This is totally right-on, I've got it working.  I also referenced this site for help with the writing of the file (I did not realize I had to make a byte array and feed bytes to write()): http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-file-in-java/

Comment: @blaughli you don't have to do this! You should use a `BufferedOutputStream` on the `FileOutputStream`. Then, you can simply feed it strings. The example shows how to implement a buffer (at least the idea) and that's not what you need. I'll put up some example code when I have Java running on this machine.

Comment: @blaughli I included an example of how this can be done (without manual buffering using byte-arrays) in the post. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache commons [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to get the file from the web. The usage of this library is very convenient. Here's the [official tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up not using the Apache Library but I did explore it and it may come in handy in the future.  Good to know it's there for all HTTP issues!

Comment: Great :) I believe it will become handy one day (it did for me)